# Best partition scheme for two ssd?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, samsung

I have two 256GB ssd drives, one is a Samsung 850 Evo on a mSATA port and the other is a Samsung 850 Pro on a SATA port. I expect the Evo is a bit slower than the Pro and is has half the lifetime expectancy (5 year vs 10 year warranty).

So what would be the best partition schema using these two drives for a personal desktop?

Comment: If curious here is a benchmark comparison: http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Samsung-850-Evo-250GB-vs-Samsung-850-Pro-256GB/2977vs2385 (though is does not distinguish between mSATA and SATA -- if there is a difference anyway)

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? Are you dual booting? Or booting Windows also? If no Windows I would suggest gpt partitioning which with Ubuntu can be used for BIOS or UEFI boot. But Windows only boots with UEFI from gpt partitioned drives.

Comment: (http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4888#ov) It's UEFI, not sure if it has an option to turn off secure boot. I have no plans to dual boot Windows though. But maybe I should consider it. If I did  the partitioning would probably be pretty simple: Windows on the Evo and Ubuntu on the Pro.

Comment: Gigabyte all seem to need you to change IOMMU setting in UEFI and add iommu=soft boot paramter. You have a setting to turn off secure boot. But in my Asus, it was Windows or "Other".  SSD now have lives comparable to hard drives. So most of you worries are unfounded. But a few settings can reduce writes.  http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead and: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd

Answer (score 0):

First, I would install Ubuntu on Samsung 850 Evo.

Then  using this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

I'll move `/home` to Samsung 850 Pro.

This has the advantage that you'll have `/home` on a separated disk, so your data remain intact in case you need to reinstall the OS. Also you'll enjoy higher life expectancy of the Pro disk where you value more the data, at your home folder.

Comment: That seems like the best course. Thanks. My only concern really is `var`. How hard is `var` going to hammer the Evo? Would it be wiser to bind `var` somewhere under `home` so the Pro takes the heavy writing? Or am I overestimating how much `var` is written to?

Comment: Not sure , but since mysql is on `/var/lib/mysql` if you have loads of mysql writes, it also makes sense to move `/var` to your 840 Pro.